# Never triggered if statements make code execution in benchmark faster? Why?

Tags: go, benchmarking

I have recently started the Go track on [exercism.io](https://www.exercism.io) and had fun optimizing the "nth-prime" calculation. Actually I came across a funny fact I can't explain. Imagine the following code:

```golang
// Package prime provides ...
package prime

// Nth function checks for the prime number on position n
func Nth(n int) (int, bool) {
        if n <= 0 {
            return 0, false
        }

        if (n == 1) {
            return 2, true
        }

        currentNumber := 1
        primeCounter := 1

        for n > primeCounter {
            currentNumber+=2
            if isPrime(currentNumber) {
                primeCounter++
            }
        }
        return currentNumber, primeCounter==n
}

// isPrime function checks if a number 
// is a prime number
func isPrime(n int) bool {
    //useless because never triggered but makes it faster??
    if n < 2 {
        println("n < 2")
        return false
    }

    //useless because never triggered but makes it faster??
    if n%2 == 0 {
        println("n%2")
        return n==2
    }

    for i := 3; i*i <= n; i+=2 {
        if n%i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

In the private function `isPrime` I have two initial if-statements that are never triggered, because I only give in uneven numbers greater than 2. The benchmark returns following:

```
Running tool: /usr/bin/go test -benchmem -run=^$ -bench ^(BenchmarkNth)$

BenchmarkNth-8           100      18114825 ns/op           0 B/op          0
```

If I remove the never triggered if-statements the benchmark goes slower:

```
Running tool: /usr/bin/go test -benchmem -run=^$ -bench ^(BenchmarkNth)$

BenchmarkNth-8            50      21880749 ns/op           0 B/op          0
```

I have run the benchmark multiple times changing the code back and forth always getting more or less the same numbers and I can't think of a reason why these two if-statements should make the execution faster. Yes it is micro-optimization, but I want to know: Why?

Here is the whole exercise from exercism with test-cases: [nth-prime](https://github.com/exercism/go/tree/master/exercises/nth-prime)

Go version i am using is 1.12.1 linux/amd64 on a manjaro i3 linux

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the code the compiler generates (however one does that in `go`; I'm mostly ignorant about this language). Could be related to branch prediction, or an accidental cache optimization due to the code's layout.

Comment: which go version are you using?

Comment: Go version is: 1.12.1 linux/amd64

Comment: Please post your benchmark

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/exercism/go/tree/master/exercises/nth-prime) is  the whole exercise with test-cases and test-file including the benchmark. To try on your pc just download the files, add the `nth_prime.go` file with my content above and you can test yourself...

Comment: Don't do `i*i` inside the loop!  Get an upper bound with sqrt.  Or on ISAs where the same instruction gives div and mod results at the same time, something like `i < n/i` is possible if it compiles efficiently.  [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204965)

Comment: Also, in your benchmark the difference between the results is huge! (that at first, might not explain why a small addition to the assembly cause this difference). The reason is you ran it for a small amount of iterations. I would suggest running it for longer so you could get better results next time.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is the compiler is guaranteed with some assertions about the input when those if's are added.
If those assertions are lifted, the compiler has to add it himself. The way it does it is by validating it on each iteration. We can take a look at the assembly code to prove it. (by passing `-gcflags=-S` to the `go test` command)

With the if's:

```
0x004b 00075 (func.go:16)  JMP     81
0x004d 00077 (func.go:16)  LEAQ    2(BX), AX
0x0051 00081 (func.go:16)  MOVQ    AX, DX
0x0054 00084 (func.go:16)  IMULQ   AX, AX
0x0058 00088 (func.go:16)  CMPQ    AX, CX
0x005b 00091 (func.go:16)  JGT     133
0x005d 00093 (func.go:17)  TESTQ   DX, DX
0x0060 00096 (func.go:17)  JEQ     257
0x0066 00102 (func.go:17)  MOVQ    CX, AX
0x0069 00105 (func.go:17)  MOVQ    DX, BX
0x006c 00108 (func.go:17)  CQO
0x006e 00110 (func.go:17)  IDIVQ   BX
0x0071 00113 (func.go:17)  TESTQ   DX, DX
0x0074 00116 (func.go:17)  JNE     77
```

Without the if's:

```
0x0016 00022 (func.go:16)  JMP     28
0x0018 00024 (func.go:16)  LEAQ    2(BX), AX
0x001c 00028 (func.go:16)  MOVQ    AX, DX
0x001f 00031 (func.go:16)  IMULQ   AX, AX
0x0023 00035 (func.go:16)  CMPQ    AX, CX
0x0026 00038 (func.go:16)  JGT     88
0x0028 00040 (func.go:17)  TESTQ   DX, DX
0x002b 00043 (func.go:17)  JEQ     102
0x002d 00045 (func.go:17)  MOVQ    CX, AX
0x0030 00048 (func.go:17)  MOVQ    DX, BX
0x0033 00051 (func.go:17)  CMPQ    BX, $-1
0x0037 00055 (func.go:17)  JEQ     64
0x0039 00057 (func.go:17)  CQO
0x003b 00059 (func.go:17)  IDIVQ   BX
0x003e 00062 (func.go:17)  JMP     69
0x0040 00064 func.go:17)  NEGQ    AX
0x0043 00067 (func.go:17)  XORL    DX, DX
0x0045 00069 (func.go:17)  TESTQ   DX, DX
0x0048 00072 (func.go:17)  JNE     24
```

Line 51 in the assembly code `0x0033 00051 (func.go:17)  CMPQ    BX, $-1` is the culprit.

Line 16, `for i := 3; i*i <= n; i+=2`, in the original Go code, is translated the same for both cases. But line 17 `if n%i == 0` that **runs every iteration** compiles to more instructions and as a result more work for the CPU in total.

Something similar in the `encoding/base64` package by ensuring the loop won't receive a `nil` value. You can take a look here:
https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/151158/3/src/encoding/base64/base64.go
This check was added intentionally. In your case, you optimized it accidentally :)

Comment: You didn't point out what the check against `-1` is for.  `LONG_MIN / -1` would raise a #DE divide overflow exception with x86's idiv instruction, and apparently Go needs to avoid that (instead of taking C's approach of saying that signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour.) Knowing that `n` can't be odd lets it skip this check.  The check is `if(i==-1){ quotient = -n; remainder = 0; }`.  Probably from that clunky `i*i < n` loop condition; Go can't prove that the loop condition will stop `i` from wrapping around to be negative? For large enough `n`, `i*i` might overflow before being false